# Eclipselink library java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: ejb-3.1, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to resolve the problem with ClassNotFoundException for 3 days, and I can't find the solution, so I'm asking for help, the problem happens when i try to use every method except find or findAll on EJB Entity Beans.

For example when I try to use method remove():

```
ctx = new InitialContext();
remote = (CategoriesRemote) ctx.lookup("CategoriesFacade/remote");
remote.remove(category);
```

I get not nice looking Exception:

```
    Exception in thread "Thread-7" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.getArguments(MethodInvocation.java:318)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:386)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.InvokableContextClassProxyHack._dynamicInvoke(InvokableContextClassProxyHack.java:53)
    at org.jboss.aop.Dispatcher.invoke(Dispatcher.java:91)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.invoke(AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:898)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:791)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:744)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:548)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:234)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:434)
    at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:165)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
    at org.jboss.system.JBossRMIClassLoader.loadClass(JBossRMIClassLoader.java:91)
    at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:247)
    at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:197)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1574)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readArray(ObjectInputStream.java:1666)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1322)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at java.rmi.MarshalledObject.get(MarshalledObject.java:142)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.getArguments(MethodInvocation.java:309)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessContainer.dynamicInvoke(StatelessContainer.java:386)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.InvokableContextClassProxyHack._dynamicInvoke(InvokableContextClassProxyHack.java:53)
    at org.jboss.aop.Dispatcher.invoke(Dispatcher.java:91)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.invoke(AOPRemotingInvocationHandler.java:82)
    at org.jboss.remoting.ServerInvoker.invoke(ServerInvoker.java:898)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.completeInvocation(ServerThread.java:791)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.processInvocation(ServerThread.java:744)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.dorun(ServerThread.java:548)
    at org.jboss.remoting.transport.socket.ServerThread.run(ServerThread.java:234)
    at org.jboss.remoting.MicroRemoteClientInvoker.invoke(MicroRemoteClientInvoker.java:216)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:1961)
    at org.jboss.remoting.Client.invoke(Client.java:804)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.client.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousClientInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousClientInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)
    at $Proxy9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:185)
    at $Proxy18.remove(Unknown Source)
    at nowyskos.modules.cms.CategorySender.run(CategorySender.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.InvokeRemoteInterceptor.invoke(InvokeRemoteInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ClientTxPropagationInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.client.SecurityClientInterceptor.invoke(SecurityClientInterceptor.java:65)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.remoting.IsLocalInterceptor.invoke(IsLocalInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousClientInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousClientInterceptor.java:143)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.remoting.PojiProxy.invoke(PojiProxy.java:62)
    at $Proxy9.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:185)
    at $Proxy18.remove(Unknown Source)
    at nowyskos.modules.cms.CategorySender.run(CategorySender.java:88)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Previously I got others exceptions regarding no security manager, I resolved it adding

```
System.setSecuritymanager(new RMISecurityManager);
```

and adding client.all file to VM Options.
But I can't find the solution for this problem.

I think that in this case the problem is not because of ejb or security manager, but because worng classpath, but in my Netbeans project I added Eclipselink library, additionaly I set the global classpath with this folder containing jar file of eclipselink which have IndirectList class.

I'm getting this error in my client application. EJB Module works on JBoss Server.

Situation for me looks weird, I don't know why find or findAll methods works perfect and remove or create crashes.

I'm really exhaused because of the problem, I don't know how to move on, please help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to what I see [here](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/search?search_type=class&java_class=org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList&start=0), this class `"org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList"` which is missing is present in glassfish distributions.  So, I guess there might be a wrong distribution of eclipselink that you are using for your project that works with JBoss AS.  A quick (but not be the right solution), would be to add one of the jars ([from here](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/search?search_type=class&java_class=org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList&start=0)) which best matches your environment to your classpath.  My advice would be to double check the version, distribution of eclipselink.