# SOAPFaultException: error unmarshalling return

Tags: web-services, persistence, jax-ws, unmarshalling

I'm having trouble getting a person-object back from my WebService and always get this error message. As I don't even use this IndirectList, I am wondering what I am possibly doing wrong. Any ideas or do you need more information?

`Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy34.checkLogin(Unknown Source)
    at KundeClient.main(KundeClient.java:20)`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem

```
error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.IndirectList
```

Maybe you can find something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048457/eclipselink-library-java-lang-classnotfoundexception).

Comment: thanks for your quick response. Unfortunately the link above did not help at all... Please let me know if you were able to solve my problem.